# Nested ifelse, return original value for 'else'?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a nested ifelse statement like this:

```
combined_data <- original %>%
  mutate(new_column = as.character(ifelse(grepl("Apple", list), "Granny Smith Apple",
                                   ifelse(grepl("Banna", list), "Organic Banana",
                                   ifelse(grepl("Spinach", list), "Baby Spinach",
                                   ifelse(grepl("Watermelon", list), "Seedless Watermelon", list))))))
```

The column "list" has say ~10 values. If it doesn't match any of those values, I want the "new_column" value to return whatever was in list. For example if column `list` has:

```
Apple
Spinach
Watermelon
Orange
Kale
```

If I run the above and use`list` then I just get a factor of the items in list and my output looks like this:

```
Granny Smith Apple
Baby Spinach
Seedless Watermelon
5
5
```

But `new_coulumn` should return:

```
Granny Smith Apple
Baby Spinach
Seedless watermelon
Orange
Kale
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Why don't you just add the unchanged items to your descriptor list to eliminate the need for more complex coding logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `dplyr`, I'd strongly recommend `case_when` as a simpler alternative to nested `ifelse()`. (`case_when` is also stricter about types, so it would have thrown an error about the factor/character mismatch).

The `case_when` version of your code is this:

```
original %>%
  mutate(new_column = case_when(
    grepl("Apple", list) ~ "Granny Smith Apple",
    grepl("Banna", list) ~ "Organic Banana",
    grepl("Spinach", list) ~ "Baby Spinach",
    grepl("Watermelon", list) ~ "Seedless Watermelon",
    TRUE ~ as.character(list)
  ))
```

I'd also challenge whether or not you need `grepl`... If you need to look for patterns *inside strings*, e.g., you want to change `"string containing Apple"` to `"Granny Smith Apple"`, then yes you need `grepl`. However, if you are doing exact matching of whole strings, you don't need `grepl`, you can just use `==`. Using `==` instead of `grepl` will be more efficient and less bug-prone (especially if you might ever have characters in your strings that might be special characters in regex).

```
original %>%
  mutate(new_column = case_when(
    list == "Apple" ~ "Granny Smith Apple",
    list == "Banna" ~ "Organic Banana",
    list == "Spinach" ~ "Baby Spinach",
    list == "Watermelon" ~ "Seedless Watermelon",
    TRUE ~ as.character(list)
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, it was returning the factor and not character.

Used this as my solution:

```
combined_data <- original %>%
  mutate(new_column = as.character(ifelse(grepl("Apple", list), "Granny Smith Apple",
                                   ifelse(grepl("Banna", list), "Organic Banana",
                                   ifelse(grepl("Spinach", list), "Baby Spinach",
                                   ifelse(grepl("Watermelon", list), "Seedless Watermelon", as.character(list)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_detect` which is also vectorized

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
original %>%
    mutate(new_column = ~ case_when(!str_detect(list, newcol)~ newcol, TRUE ~ list))
```